# How to split real-time video into image?

Tags: python, opencv, video

By using opencv on python. I recorded video and then split it into pictures but it took a long time so I want to split video into pictures immediately when I'm recording video. I found code on internet but it can capture only 1 pic.

```
import cv2

def main():
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    frame = cam.read()[1]
    cv2.imwrite(filename='img%d.jpg',img=frame)

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Can anyone help me? I'm very new with python and opencv.

Comment: use the imwrite function and provide a different filename each time (for example by using and string and an incrementing number value. So your question might be how to add a number to a string. Unfortunately I can't help there because Im not that familiar with python

Answer (score 1):

You didn't increase file name, so it get overwritten again and again. Also, you need a `while` loop. Try:

```
import cv2

def main():
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    frameNum = 0
    isCaptured = True
    while True:
        isCapture, frame = cam.read()
        if not isCapture:
            # no more frame, exit loop
            break
        frameNum = frameNum + 1
        fileName = 'img{:d}.jpg'.format(frameNum)
        cv2.imwrite(filename=fileName,img=frame)

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thx so much for your help :D.